# Игнорирование определенных тегов в XPath lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то игнорировать определенные html-теги, находящиеся внутри текста при разборе XPath? В моем случае это тег `<br>`. Пример:

```py
from lxml import html


def main():
    html_page = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="table">
    <h3>Table title</h3>

    <div>
        <div><span>Title item 1</span></div>
        <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><span>Title item 2</span></div>
        <span>Item 2<br>Item 2.1<br>Item 2.2</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><span>Title item 3</span></div>
        <span>Item 3</span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><span>Title item 4</span></div>
        <span>Item 4</span>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
'''
    tree = html.document_fromstring(html_page)

    item_titles = tree.xpath('//div[@id="table"]/div/div/span/text()')
    item_values = tree.xpath('//div[@id="table"]/div/span/text()')

    print(item_titles)
    print(item_values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
['Title item 1', 'Title item 2', 'Title item 3', 'Title item 4']
['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 2.1', 'Item 2.2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']
```

а мне нужен такой:

```
['Title item 1', 'Title item 2', 'Title item 3', 'Title item 4']
['Item 1', 'Item 2 Item 2.1 Item 2.2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4']
```

т.е. из-за находящегося среди текста `<span>Item 2<br>Item 2.1<br>Item 2.2</span>` тега `<br>` результат разбивается на отдельные элементы списка, что в моем случае совсем неправильно, т.к. `Item 2<br>Item 2.1<br>Item 2.2` являются элементами одного значения.

Я делал свой ламерский костыль в виде `replace()`:

```py
temp = html_page.replace('<br>', ' ')
tree = html.document_fromstring(temp)
```

но реальная html-страница сильно напичкана всем и вся и, естественно, такой костыль бьет по производительности, да и решение это, мягко говоря, такое себе... Чувствую, должно быть элегантное решение, просто я чего-то не знаю..?

Comment: Я может чего не понял, но чем Вам `bs4` (aka BeautifulSoup) не угодил?

Comment: У него нету XPath. И, если не ошибаюсь, при аналогичном разборе он вернет все значения единой текстовой строкой, где элементы будут разделены пробелами, табуляцией и т.п. Мне и нужен результирующий список и.XPath делает то, что нужно, затык только в затесавшихся среди текста тегах.

Comment: `<br/>` в текстовой строке == '\n', кто мешает сделать `.split('\n')`? или, что еще лучше `re.split(r'\s*\n+\s*', text)`

Comment: Мне интересно, если попробовать теги нормализировать, т.е. `<br>` -> `<br />`, эффект останется?

Comment: @0andriy, останется. Как я понимаю, lxml учитывает именно буквенное значение тегов, а спецсимволы в его составе предполагает разные варианты. К тому же, `<br>` - валидный тег для html5, как и `<br />`, и `<br/>`.

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо за ответ. Но как в `bs4` быть с другими вложенными тегами?  На шаблоне `<span>Item 2<br>Item 2.1<br>Item 2.2 <span class="tooltip"><span>Tooltip text-text-text</span></span>other text</span>` в `bs4` при `soup.select("div[id='table']>div>span")` выведется вообще весь текст, включая вложенных тегов. Их как вырезать регуляркой? В `lxml` `tree.xpath('//div[@id="table"]/div/span/text()')` выведет только текст запрошенных тегов `span`, не затрагивая вложенных. Как добиться такого же от `bs4`?

Comment: @EvgeniyPorovozoff, поверьте, при детальном изучении библиотеки `bs4` вы найдете ответы на все интересующие вас вопросы. Скажу только одно что, так любимую Вами `lxml`, `bs4` использует как один из возможных парсеров html

Comment: @Namerek, я Вам верю, но это не отвечает на вопрос, в т.ч. как это сделать на так настоятельно агитируемой Вами `bs4`. Если знаете, подскажите, буду благодарен. И да, я прекрасно знаю, что `bs4` может использовать `lxml` (и это  вариант парсера рекомендуемый самими разработчиками) в качестве основного парсера, однако, под своим АПИ, прямого доступа к АПИ `lxml` из `bs4` нету, да и используется `lxml` только для ускорения разбора.

Comment: Никаких регулярных выражений! Судя по всему вам уровнем выше надо брать, и пробегать по детям самому. Т.е. начинать от `//div[@id="table"]/div/span`. Либо углубиться в XPath методы и функции. Там много всего есть, может быть получится что-то вытащить...